# AngularJS - Filter view by month with ng-click

Tags: angularjs, date, filter, angularjs-ng-click

I would like to filter my view with a simple link. I have several objects which all contain a date. Eg. If I click March only data with "Startdate" March should be displayed. I searched the web but found nothing which worked for me. This is my json object and the criteria should be "Startdate".

**trips.son**

```
[{
  "Startdate": "Thu Jan 02 2014 00:00:00 +0100",
  "DAYS": [{
    "DATE": "Thu Jan 02 2014 00:00:00 +0100",
    "IATA": "TXL",
    "DUTY": "6:10"
  }]
}, {
  "Startdate": "Sun Jan 05 2014 00:00:00 +0100",
  "DAYS": [{
    "DATE": "Sun Jan 05 2014 00:00:00 +0100",
    "IATA": "CBTH",
    "DUTY": "8:07"
  }]
}, {
  "Startdate": "Wed Sep 24 2014 00:00:00 +0200",
  "DAYS": [{
    "DATE": "Wed Sep 24 2014 00:00:00 +0200",
    "IATA": "BCN",
    "DUTY": "9:35"
  }, {
    "DATE": "Thu Sep 25 2014 00:00:00 +0200",
    "IATA": "BCN",
    "DUTY": "15:34"
  }]
}, {
  "Startdate": "Sat Sep 27 2014 00:00:00 +0200",
  "DAYS": [{
    "DATE": "Sat Sep 27 2014 00:00:00 +0200",
    "IATA": "CPH",
    "DUTY": "4:44"
  }]
}]
```

Here you can see what I mean:

***UPDATED:*** **[plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/tgUvtd1IVWQDw8UH3iPb?p=info)**

By default only January should by displayed - changing the view when each link is clicked !

Comment: I'm confused, the dropdown filter appears to be working correctly in the plnkr that you posted.  did you find the problem or are you having some other issue?

Comment: there is a problem with my plunker ! it won't show up the actual version ! nevertheless I just found a way of doing what I want ! I will post it soon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way which works for me ! Maybe not the best but it will do the job.

Added StartdateMonth as the name of the month to my scope:

```
var date = new Date($scope.trips[i].Startdate);
            $scope.trips[i].Startdate = date;
            var names = ["Januar", "Februar", "März", "April", "Mai", "Juni", "Juli", "August", "September", "Oktober", "November", "Dezember"];
            $scope.trips[i].StartdateMonth = names[date.getMonth()];
```

create ng-click for tab:

```
<li role="presentation"><a ng-click="myFilter = {StartdateMonth: 'Januar'}">Januar</a></li>
<li role="presentation"><a ng-click="myFilter = {StartdateMonth: 'Februar'}">Februar</a></li>
```

finally add the filter:

```
<div ng-repeat="trip in trips | filter: myFilter">
```